# Tidier HTML/CSS Code

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I have got my site looking how I want it to but I feel the code is extremely untidy and was wondering if there was a simpler way to achieve the same layout with friendlier code.

[Site here](http://adamhuxtable.com/nivo/)

Also the footer, I would prefer it if I could get it to be a separate div outside of the content, but at the moment its the only way I can sort of achieve the look I want.

Comment: Your code's pretty tidy... and this might belong on Code Review.

Comment: Eh... Unless Google Chrome is tidying up the source it's quote tidy already.

Comment: Ok thanks guys! just looked untidy to my eyes but it had been a long days, thanks for your time :)

Comment: Your code looks tidy to me, though I'd move the inline styles to the CSS files. More importantly though, your doctype `<!DOCTYPE>` is bogus and will cause quirks mode in browsers. I suggest `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead.

Comment: Forgot I left the inline styles in there was for testing and made the amendment for the DOCTYPE, thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problems with your layout or code - everything looks pretty tidy to me ...

The Divs are clearly laid out to match the flow of your site - keep it as it is ....

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it has it is, any ideas on how I could get the footer to display underneath the content div rather than the inside? Been playing around but to no avail.

Comment: @adamhuxtable Same display on the screen but with the div below the content ?

Comment: Aye that would be correct, but when trying to achieve this, it wouldn't go there instead its was positioning under the carousel rather than under the content...